# Finding a spesific string and getting its line in PYTHON 3.X

Tags: python, python-3.x

Lets say I am trying to find a spesific string in a txt file in python and I want to get that line how do I do it?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say your file is called `file.txt`, you can use `next()` on a generator expression which yields the indexes of lines in the file containing `your_string`. To be able to work with the indexes and the contents, we can use `enumerate()`:

```
next(i for i, l in enumerate(open('file.txt').readlines()) if 'your_string' in l)
```

Comment: Why read the whole file into memory with `readlines()`? And why not use use the `with` statement and explicitly close the file handle?

Comment: It is a poorly asked question so my answer will help the OP but isn't the best I agree. One-liners are great though and with short files and quick tasks, Python was built to be quick to whip together

Comment: and how do I get the number of the line

Comment: @ÖmerKural What do you mean? Running this *does* give the number of the line (starting with `0`, so if you want them to start with `1`, just do `+ 1` :) )

Comment: oh yeah thx :D please check my new Q out!